# API: Retrieve Record Types for Contact

Tags: api, record-type, contact

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all record types relating to the Contact object in Salesforce using the Enterprise WSDl in C#. Currently I am setting a Contact object like this:

```
var contact = new Contact();
contact.Email = user.Email.
contact.FirstName = user.FirstName;
etc ...
```

The Contact object has a RecordType property but I need to retrieve all of the record types first in order to assign the correct object.

Currently I cannot find a way of doing this. At first I thought RecordTypeMapping would allow me to do this but it seems to be a middle object between something that could retrieve record types.

How can I retrieve a list of all record types for Contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the RecordType object:

```
select Id, Name, Description, DeveloperName, IsActive from RecordType
where sobjecttype='Contact'
```

This will give you all the possible values for the recordtypeid

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once I retrieve this result is it just a matter of creating a new RecordType object setting the properties to the values returned?

Comment: You use the ID value that you have retrieved from the query on RecordType as the value to insert into contact.recordtypeid. For example contact.recordtypeid = [select id from recordtype where sobjecttype='Contact' and developername='Supplier']; (although you probably want to query the recordtype and cache results, but this should give you the idea)

Answer (score 2):

You can query the `RecordType` table. A sample SOQL query would be:

```
SELECT DeveloperName,Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Contact'
```

You might also be able to do this with a describe call.